# Better way to find index of item from ArrayList<CustomObject>

Tags: java, search, arraylist, indexof

First of all, please correct me If I am wrong. I want to find index of Item (i.e String value) from `ArrayList<CustomType>` without using For Loop.

POJO:

```
id;
name;
```

Code:

```
ArrayList<POJO> list = new ArrayList<POJO>;

//Lots of data added to these list...
```

**Now I want to find the id of particular name from the arraylist without using below kind of for loop.**

```
String id = null;
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if("ABCD".equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i).getName())) {
        id = list.get(i).getId();
        break;
    }
}
```

Ideally I don't want to implement the For loop because in some cases i have 500+ data inside the List and to find index using a For loop is not a good way to do this.

Comment: Maybe you should use `Map<String, POJO>` with the `String` being the name instead?

Comment: 500 elements is not a lot, chances are this loop has no real effect on the performance of your code (even 'though it is inefficient).

Comment: @JoachimSauer, But I have to think of future also. May be it increase up to thousands or more than that. So that is the concern. BYW thanks for your kind response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for your kind and quick response. But a Special thanks to [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer). You are absolutely right that **500 elements is not a lot, chances are this loop has no real effect on the performance of your code (even 'though it is inefficient).** Even I try it up to 5000 elements and still there is no negative impact on the performance.

Thank you all once again and thank you for your comment [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `list.indexOf()`, but in order to make it work, you need to override `equals` and `hasCode` of your `POJO`.

By default, two objects will be considered equal if they have the same reference. You can overwrite `equals` to work for your case:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (!(o instanceof POJO)) {
    return false;
  }
  POJO other = (POJO) o;
  return name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.getName());
}
```

Overridding equals would suggest you override `hashCode`. For example:

```
public int hashCode() {
  return name.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: This does not address the inefficiency mentioned in the question, it's "just" another way to do what the code in the question does. Also: depending on the size/use of the POJO, instantiating one just to search for a equally-named on is a bad idea. Also: most of the time having an `equals()` implementation on a POJO that *doesn't* consider the `id` is a bad idea.

Comment: Is there an option using a `java.util.Comparator` instead?

Comment: @Martin You can use the Comparator for sorting and then doing a binary search.

Comment: @Dan Interesting idea. But I would still need to overloads `equals ()` — which does not help if you need to search for different predicates. To bad I can't use Java 8 which seem to have this function.

Answer (score 4):

Finding element in this way where complexity would be give you BIG-O (n). I think if you Map that would gives you better result.

`HashMap` would be better choice. - Where Complexity would be O(1).

Comment: Ok. Yes I can use HashMap<String, String> for this. Thanks for your suggestion @Quoi.

Comment: If i have a List only than it take again BIG-O (n) to convert List to  Map.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati - the conversion is BIG-O(n) but whenever you query, it's O(1). if you need to frequently query,  it's better to convert to map.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to search on a string value you should use a `HashMap` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `List.indexOf()` - but you must **make sure you also override `POJO.equals()`** - (and as part of the convention - also `hashCode()`.

Note that nevertheless - the result will be `O(n)` - an alternative could be to use an *sorted array* (`POJO[]`) and use [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) or a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)/[`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

If you use an array and `binarySearch()` - you must make sure that `POJO` also implements [`Comparable<POJO>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

---

Note that for a static data (your list doesn't change often/at all) - though arrays and `binarySearch()` is "worse" then `HashSet` in terms of big-O notations, in practice - it is often much faster, especially for relatively short lists.

In terms of big-O notation, a hash based solution offers a `O(1)` average case accessing.

Comment: `binarySearch` also requires the `List` to be sorted.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yeap, of course - I thought it was implicitly obvious, I'll add an explicit indication.

Comment: Is there an option using a `java.util.Comparator` or similar instead? So one could search for different predicates.

Answer (score 0):

To answer to this question, I launched a benchmark with JMH.

Without surprise classic loop is the efficient way to do that.

I used a `DATA_ARRAY` containing 17576 elements and the searched element is at the index 7733.

Using classic Loop - 0,030 ± 0,001 ms/op:

```
int i = 0;
for (String str : DATA_ARRAYLIST) {
    if (str.equals("lll")) break;
    i++;
}
```

Using indexOf and override the equals method: 0,030 ± 0,002  ms/op

```
MY_DATA_ARRAYLIST.indexOf("lll");
```

Using data range: 0,082 ± 0,003  ms/op

```
OptionalInt integer = IntStream.range(0, DATA_ARRAYLIST.size())
            .filter(i -> DATA_ARRAYLIST.get(i).equals("lll"))
            .findFirst();
```

Using indexOf after having found with a stream: 0,074 ± 0,008  ms/op

```
String result = DATA_ARRAYLIST.stream().filter(e -> e.equals("lll")).findFirst().get();
DATA_ARRAYLIST.indexOf(result);
```

Using indexOf after having found with a parallelStream: 0,087 ± 0,023  ms/op

```
String result = DATA_ARRAYLIST.parallelStream().filter(e -> e.equals("lll")).findFirst().get();
DATA_ARRAYLIST.indexOf(result);
```

However if the searched element is in the last index:

- Classic Loop : 0,066 ± 0,002  ms/op
- Parallel Stream : 0,121 ± 0,023  ms/op
- Stream : 0,161 ± 0,024  ms/op

And then if you have 456 976 elements:

- Classic Loop : 2,172 ± 0,297  ms/op
- Parallel Stream : 3,145 ± 0,380  ms/op
- Stream : 6,081 ± 0,097  ms/op

As you can see it's really hard to beat the Loop!